# Which part of the sentence has an error

Tags: exam-questions

*The need to set up / a good library in the locality / has been in the minds of people / for some time now .*

Please explain

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Can a _need_ be in somebody's mind? Also, technically, the slashes shouldn't be there.

Comment: http://www.campusgate.co.in/2014/03/error-detection-articles.html?m=1 refer this link for answer. I just copied your question in Google and got this answer.

Comment: The proposed correction on that site is nonsense. "In people's minds" would be more idiomatic, but "in the minds of people" is fine. "In the minds of the people" would only make sense if the relevant group of people had already been identified in the discourse.

Comment: @ColinFine one could argue that the relevant group of people _is_ (implicitly) identified by mentioning that the library would be _in the locality_ making it unlikely that people _outside_ the locality have given it much thought. Even so, I agree that the question (and its answer) are still far-fetched.

Comment: @Colin Fine Just "people" can be any people anywhere. But "the people" to refer a specific group of people . Right?

Comment: @Raj33 Right. So without any context, i.e. when there is only the one sentence to go on, the answer should be "people". The list that you linked makes the same error in other sentences, like 17 and 23.

Comment: Actually, particularly if the same is true of other sentences, I wonder if this might be something that is different in Indian English. In another thread I have just been pointing out that people are saying something is wrong, when I know that it is used in Indian English. I wonder if that might be the case here, and Indian English requires "the" while other Englishes don't. I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a slip because the sentence given does not contain an error. What may be behind the slip is this. The noun "people" has a number of different meanings. I suspect that the creators of the exercise had a specific meaning in mind that does call for "the."

One meaning of "people" is a synonym for "human beings" in general. In the sentence "Most people like ice cream," what is meant is nothing more than that the majority of human beings like ice cream. The sentence in your exercise can be read in that sense. Some unspecified human beings thought a local library was needed. The definite article is not needed, and there is no error.

Another meaning of "people" is all those human beings that make up some specific group under consideration. Winning politicians in a democracy love to say that "The people have spoken" even if 49.9% of the actual voters disagreed and 40% of those eligible to vote failed to do so. When used in that sense, we need the definite article: "the people" means the particular group of people being discussed. Adding "the" to the sentence in your exercise is necessary to make it mean that some noteworthy group of human beings in the community thought that a library was needed. If that is the meaning intended, then "the" is indeed needed.